# Spark Streaming: Aggregating datastream multiple times

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

I have a spark streaming job which reads the data from multiple kafka topics. 
Now I want to aggregate data on multiple `window intervals` and save it to the database.

Is it possible to do this way? Or I will need a separate spark job to do another level of aggregation.

Would data be lost if dataset processed second time?

### Aggregation 1:

```
private void buildStream1(Dataset<Row> sourceDataset) {
      Dataset<Row> query = sourceDataset
        .withWatermark("timestamp", "120 seconds")
        .select(
            col("timestamp"),
            col("datacenter"),
            col("platform")
        )
        .groupBy(
            functions.window(col("timestamp"), 120 seconds, 60 seconds).as("timestamp"),
            col("datacenter"),
            col("platform")
        )
        .agg(
            count(lit(1)).as("count")
        );
      startKafkaStream(query);
  }
```

### Aggregation 2:

```
private void buildStream1(Dataset<Row> sourceDataset) {
      Dataset<Row> query = sourceDataset
        .withWatermark("timestamp", "10 minutes")
        .select(
            col("timestamp"),
            col("datacenter"),
            col("platform")
        )
        .groupBy(
            functions.window(col("timestamp"), 10 minutes, 5 minutes).as("timestamp"),
            col("datacenter"),
            col("platform")
        )
        .agg(
            count(lit(1)).as("count")
        );
      startKafkaStream(query);
  }
```

### Write both streams:

```
private void startKafkaStream(Dataset<Row> aggregatedDataset) {
    aggregatedDataset
        .select(to_json(struct("*")).as("value"))
        .writeStream()
        .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
        .option("truncate", false)
        .format("console")
        .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(10 minutes))
        .start();
  }
```

Comment: Any progress here as it is an interesting point